# Textbox won't move

Tags: python, tkinter

I coded a program where you can add text boxes and images. When you click and hover on the textbox it shows two buttons: **Bin and Move.**

**BIN BUTTON:** Clicking on it deletes the textbox.

**MOVE BUTTON:** Hold clicking it allows you to move the text box around.

So far the bin button works, but not the move button. When hold clicking it won't move the textbox around. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

*I'm still fairly new to Python so any advice is more than welcome!*

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

def save_file():
    file_path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".leaff", filetypes=[("Leaf Files", "*.leaff")])
    if file_path:
        # Perform saving logic here
        # Update the window title with the saved file name
        new_window.title(file_path)

def save_as_file():
    file_path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(filetypes=[("Leaf Files", "*.leaff")])
    if file_path:
        # Perform saving logic here
        # Update the window title with the saved file name
        new_window.title(file_path)

def load_new_branch():
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Leaf Files", "*.leaff")])
    if file_path:
        # Perform loading logic here
        # Update the window title with the loaded file name
        new_window.title(file_path)

def create_new_branch():
    window.withdraw()  # Hide the main menu window

    # Create a new window
    global new_window
    new_window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    new_window.geometry("700x400")
    new_window.title("New Branch")

    def add_text():
        text_entry = tk.Entry(new_window, bd=0)
        text_entry.pack(pady=2)

        def on_entry_hover(event):
            text_entry.config(highlightbackground="black", highlightcolor="black", highlightthickness=2)

        def on_entry_leave(event):
            text_entry.config(highlightbackground="", highlightcolor="", highlightthickness=0)

        def on_entry_click(event):
            on_entry_hover(event)
            delete_button.place(x=text_entry.winfo_x() + text_entry.winfo_width() - 20,
                               y=text_entry.winfo_y() + text_entry.winfo_height() + 5)
            move_button.place(x=delete_button.winfo_x() - 35,
                              y=delete_button.winfo_y())

        text_entry.bind("<Enter>", on_entry_hover)
        text_entry.bind("<Leave>", on_entry_leave)
        text_entry.bind("<Button-1>", on_entry_click)

        # Create the delete button
        def delete_text():
            text_entry.destroy()
            delete_button.destroy()
            move_button.destroy()

        delete_button = tk.Button(new_window, image=delete_icon, command=delete_text)
        delete_button.image = delete_icon

        # Create the move button
        def move_text(event):
            def on_drag_start(event):
                text_entry._drag_data = {'x': event.x, 'y': event.y}

            def on_drag_motion(event):
                delta_x = event.x - text_entry._drag_data['x']
                delta_y = event.y - text_entry._drag_data['y']
                new_x = text_entry.winfo_x() + delta_x
                new_y = text_entry.winfo_y() + delta_y
                text_entry.place(x=new_x, y=new_y)
                text_entry._drag_data = {'x': event.x, 'y': event.y}

            def on_drag_release(event):
                text_entry.unbind('<B1-Motion>')
                text_entry.unbind('<ButtonRelease-1>')

            text_entry.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', on_drag_start)
            text_entry.bind('<B1-Motion>', on_drag_motion)
            text_entry.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', on_drag_release)

        move_button = tk.Button(new_window, image=move_icon)
        move_button.image = move_icon
        move_button.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', move_text)

    def add_image():
        # Add image logic here
        print("Image added")

    def return_to_main_menu():
        new_window.destroy()  # Close the branch window
        window.deiconify()  # Show the main menu window

    # Create the file menu
    file_menu = tk.Menu(new_window)
    file_menu.add_command(label="Save", command=save_file)
    file_menu.add_command(label="Save As", command=save_as_file)
    file_menu.add_command(label="Exit", command=return_to_main_menu)

    # Create the add menu
    add_menu = tk.Menu(new_window)
    add_menu.add_command(label="Text", command=add_text)
    add_menu.add_command(label="Image", command=add_image)

    # Create the main menu bar
    menu_bar = tk.Menu(new_window)
    menu_bar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file_menu)
    menu_bar.add_cascade(label="Add", menu=add_menu)
    new_window.config(menu=menu_bar)

# Create the main window
window = tk.Toplevel(root)
window.geometry("700x400")
window.title("Leaf")

# Load the background image
original_image = Image.open("images/Leaf.jpg")
resized_image = original_image.resize((700, 400), Image.ANTIALIAS)  # Resize to window dimensions
background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_image)

# Create a label with the background image
background_label = tk.Label(window, image=background_image)
background_label.place(relx=0, rely=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

button_width = 20

# Create the "Create new branch" button
create_button = tk.Button(window, text="Create new branch", command=create_new_branch, width=button_width)
create_button.place(relx=0.64, rely=0.375)

# Create the "Load new branch" button
load_button = tk.Button(window, text="Load new branch", command=load_new_branch, width=button_width)
load_button.place(relx=0.64, rely=0.475)

# Load the delete button image
delete_icon = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/bin.png"))

# Load the move button image
move_icon = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/move.png"))

window.mainloop()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvYNc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code worked mostly for me, except the movement was janky. Here's an updated `on_drag_motion` method that fixes the movement.

```
def on_drag_motion(event):
    widget = event.widget
    x = widget.winfo_x() - widget._drag_data['x'] + event.x
    y = widget.winfo_y() - widget._drag_data['y'] + event.y
    widget.place(x=x, y=y)
```

Also, make sure you click the `Move` button, but then drag the text box to wherever you want it to go.

Hope this helps!

---

Edit: [Streamable demo video](https://streamable.com/lk5pq0)

---

Edit after OP comment.

```
def move_text(event):
    def on_drag_start(event):
        move_button._drag_data = {'x': event.x, 'y': event.y}

    def on_drag_motion(event):
        widget = event.widget
        x = widget.winfo_x() - widget._drag_data['x'] + event.x
        y = widget.winfo_y() - widget._drag_data['y'] + event.y


        tx = text_entry.winfo_x() - widget._drag_data['x'] + event.x
        ty = text_entry.winfo_y() - widget._drag_data['y'] + event.y
        widget.place(x=x, y=y)
        text_entry.place(x=tx, y=ty)

    def on_drag_release(event):
        move_button.unbind('<B1-Motion>')
        move_button.unbind('<ButtonRelease-1>')

    on_drag_start(event)
    move_button.bind('<B1-Motion>', on_drag_motion)
    move_button.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', on_drag_release)

move_button = tk.Button(new_window, text='move')
move_button.image = move_icon
move_button.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', move_text)
```

This should allow you to hold the move button and drag, and the text entry will move with the mouse.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding! It doesn't seem to work on my end at all. Is there any way it's possible to make the textbox move while holding the move button instead of moving the textbox itself after clicking the move button?

Comment: Well yes, that is possible. I just was unaware you wanted that to be the way it operated since your code has the `bind`s all set to `text_entry` and not `move_button`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @NobleF Glad to help. I'd appreciate it if you mark this question as solved by clicking the check mark underneath the up/down arrows of my answer.